# How to say "dull the knife"?

Tags: translation

I want to translate "Using the knife on these types of surfaces will dull the knife." This I find to be difficult grammatically as well. However, I'm not sure how to say "dull" in Mandarin, and google doesn't provide much help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Dull` (adjective) as in 'a dull knife' is `钝` in Mandarin. There is not a two-character version for it.

`Dull` (vt.) as in 'dull the knife' is `使..变钝`, literally 'make .. become dull'.

Example of 钝 (adjective):

> It's impossible to cut a pineapple with such a dull knife.
>
> 用一把这么**钝**的刀子切菠萝是不可能的。

To translate your sentence, which is also an example of 使..变钝:

> Using the knife on these types of surfaces will dull the knife.
>
> 在这些类型的表面上用刀会**使**刀**变钝**。

Related words:

- (Knife or blade) sharp (adjective): 快 or 锋利.

快 must be used in the same sentence as the noun (刀), otherwise it doesn't mean 'sharp'. 锋利 can be used standalone.

- Sharpen the knife (V+O): 磨刀.

An example using all these words:

> 刀子用多了会变钝，磨一磨就又变快了。
>
> Knife becomes dull after some use. Burnish it and it will be sharp again.

Comment: You can certainly stick another character to front and make it two character, such as 粗钝. Of course, the core part is 钝.

Comment: @user58955 Sure but 粗钝 is not a common word and can't replace 钝 in most circumstances.

Comment: not uncommon in 武侠小说 (kongfu novels)

Comment: @user58955 Indeed. This answer is speaking in the context of OP's sentence:)

Comment: Actually, according to your translation, 变钝 is an acceptable word, literally "become dull". "在这些表面上用刀会使它变钝。"

Comment: @congusbongus Good point, actually I misread the question and thought it was asking for the adjective form. I have updated the answer. Thanks for pointing out!

Answer (score 1):

You may say

磨钝一把刀

pinyin: mo2 dun4 yi4 ba3 dau1

Explanation:

磨钝: make something dull.

一: a

把: classifier of knife.

刀: knife.